# RenderPartial Problem (While sending data to master page)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, automapper

I am trying to send some data the master page. I am using Razor as my View Engine, and AutoMapper to map between Domain and View Models. Below is my code:

```
//the partial view action method:
public ActionResult RenderCategories()
{
    IEnumerable<TopLevelCategory> categories = _categoryService.GetTopLevelCategories();
    var viewModel = new MasterPageViewModel
                    {
                        Categories =
                            Mapper.Map
                            <IEnumerable<TopLevelCategory>, IEnumerable<ParentCategory>>(categories)
                    };

    return View(viewModel);
}

//the partial view file: (this is just a test for now)
@model Sharwe.MVC.ViewModels.MasterPageViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Categories) {
      @item.Name
}

public class MasterPageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ParentCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling the partial view using @Html.RenderPartial("RenderCategories") from inside my _Layout.cshtml file. But I keep getting the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The
>   best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`RenderPartial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492503.aspx) extension method writes directly to the output stream and has no return type (`void`). So here's the correct syntax to call it:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("RenderCategories");}
```

or if you prefer you could use the [`Partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402898.aspx) extension method:

```
@Html.Partial("RenderCategories")
```

Contrast those with their equivalents in the WebForms view engine:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("RenderCategories"); %>
<%= Html.Partial("RenderCategories") %>
```

Comment: Ah I see. That actually worked, but now the model type of the partial view is conflicting with the model type of the @RenderBody region. Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: You can pass the correct model as second argument to the `RenderPartial` method.

Comment: I tried to do that but I couldn't get it right. I still get the same error. Mind showing me an example please?

Comment: Follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345029/renderpartial-conflicting-model-types